# Add capabilities to custom post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating custom plugin in which I would like to add capabilities as per User role for particular custom post type dynamically.

```
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'elementor-siteset' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => $this->slug ),
    'capability_type'    => 'member',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title'),
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-groups',
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'can_export' => true,
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post' => 'edit_member',
        'edit_posts' => 'edit_members',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_members',
        'publish_posts' => 'edit_members',
        'read_post' => 'read_member',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_members',
        'delete_post' => 'delete_member',
        'create_posts' => 'edit_members'
    ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true
);
```

**This is my WordPress backend.**

[image]

I want to make it dynamically. If I save from my backed then it should save the capabilities for the particular role for that particular CPT. I will resolve this once I got solution of following thing.

**I want to do this. Following code has been added only for the testing. I would like to add only read, edit and delete capabilities for member CPT for particular role. How can I achieve that?**

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the administrator role
    $admins = get_role( 'editor' );

    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_member' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_members' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_other_members' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'publish_members' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'delete_member' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_member' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_private_members' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps', 10,2);
```

Above code is removing whole CPT "Member" for particular role. If I add `remove_cap()` to remove any of the capabilities then it will not affect as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_gallery' );

function register_cpt_gallery() {
$labels = array( 
'name' => _x( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Gallery', 'gallery' ),
'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'gallery' ),
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Gallery', 'gallery' ),
'new_item' => _x( 'New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
'view_item' => _x( 'View Gallery', 'gallery' ),
'search_items' => _x( 'Search Galleries', 'gallery' ),
'not_found' => _x( 'No galleries found', 'gallery' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No galleries found in Trash', 'gallery' ),
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Gallery:', 'gallery' ),
'menu_name' => _x( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
);

$args = array( 
  'labels' => $labels,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'description' => 'Image galleries for teachers classes',
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author'),
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/imagegallery.png',
  'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'exclude_from_search' => false,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'can_export' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capabilities' => array(
    'edit_post' => 'edit_gallery',
    'edit_posts' => 'edit_galleries',
    'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_galleries',
    'publish_posts' => 'publish_galleries',
    'read_post' => 'read_gallery',
    'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_galleries',
    'delete_post' => 'delete_gallery'
  ),
// as pointed out by iEmanuele, adding map_meta_cap will map the meta correctly 
'map_meta_cap' => true
);

register_post_type( 'gallery', $args );
}
```

the additional capabilities should be added to a role for the permissions to actually work in the backend, including the 'administrator' - for example:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
// gets the administrator role
$admins = get_role( 'administrator' );

$admins->add_cap( 'edit_gallery' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_galleries' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'edit_other_galleries' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'publish_galleries' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'read_gallery' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'read_private_galleries' ); 
$admins->add_cap( 'delete_gallery' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

I hope this is useful for you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for giving me time but I have already tried this. This code not give only read capability, Only edit capability and only delete capability to the particular role. Let me know if you have any solution to give only read, edit, delete and add capability to particular role. I have tried all the ways.

Comment: Here is delete code check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701343/wordpress-capabilities-custom-post-type-delete-post-is-not-working

Comment: As per my question, I am looking for complete read, write, delete and edit capabilities thing. I have also checked most the plugins they not provide same thing.